# Chromecast sender application isn't connecting to Android Receiver app , always connecting to web receiver

Tags: android, chromecast, android-tv

I followed this codelab [Cast Connect with ATV App](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cast-connect-atv/?authuser=0&hl=ro-RO&skip_cache=true#0) and this codelab for [Cast-enable an Android app](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cast-receiver#7) , After that

- I added my Chromecast as testing device in cast console
- Signed the ATV app
- Installed in tv box and tried to cast from the sender app , but it opens the web receiver not the ATV app
  Sender AndroidManifest.xml

```xml
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    
        <queries>
            <intent>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    
                <data android:mimeType="video/* , application/x-mpegURL" />
            </intent>
        </queries>
    
        <application
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
            android:protectionLevel="signature"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.JMXPlayer"
            android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
            tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute">
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AD_MANAGER_APP"
                android:value="true" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.OPTIONS_PROVIDER_CLASS_NAME"
                android:value="com.stream.jmxplayer.casty.CastOptionProvider" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Sender Option Provider class

```java
    
    public class CastOptionProvider implements OptionsProvider {
        @Override
        public CastOptions getCastOptions(Context context) {
            CastOptions customCastOptions = Casty.customCastOptions;
            if (customCastOptions == null) {
                List<String> buttonActions = createButtonActions();
                int[] compatButtonAction = {1, 3};
    
                NotificationOptions notificationOptions = new NotificationOptions.Builder()
                        .setActions(buttonActions, compatButtonAction)
                        .setTargetActivityClassName(ExpandedControlsActivity.class.getName())
                        .build();
    
                CastMediaOptions mediaOptions = new CastMediaOptions.Builder()
                        .setNotificationOptions(notificationOptions)
                        .setExpandedControllerActivityClassName(ExpandedControlsActivity.class.getName())
                        .build();
                LaunchOptions launchOptions = new LaunchOptions.Builder()
                        .setRelaunchIfRunning(true)
                        .setAndroidReceiverCompatible(true).build();
    
                return new CastOptions.Builder()
                        .setReceiverApplicationId(Casty.receiverId)
                        .setCastMediaOptions(mediaOptions)
                        .setLaunchOptions(launchOptions)
                        .build();
            } else {
                return customCastOptions;
            }
        }
    
        private List<String> createButtonActions() {
            return Arrays.asList(MediaIntentReceiver.ACTION_REWIND,
                    MediaIntentReceiver.ACTION_TOGGLE_PLAYBACK,
                    MediaIntentReceiver.ACTION_FORWARD,
                    MediaIntentReceiver.ACTION_STOP_CASTING);
        }
    
        @Override
        public List<SessionProvider> getAdditionalSessionProviders(Context context) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Receiver AndroidManifest.xml

```xml
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    
        <uses-feature
            android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
            android:required="false" />
        <uses-feature
            android:name="android.software.leanback"
            android:required="true" />
    
        <application
            android:name=".JmxApplication"
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:appComponentFactory="androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.JMXPlayerCast">
    
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.cast.tv.RECEIVER_OPTIONS_PROVIDER_CLASS_NAME"
                android:value="com.stream.jmxplayercast.CastReceiverOptionsProvider" />
    
            <activity
                android:name=".ui.MainActivity"
                android:banner="@drawable/main_logo"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:launchMode="singleTask"
                android:logo="@drawable/circle_cropped_logo"
                android:screenOrientation="landscape">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
    
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.cast.tv.action.LAUNCH" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
    
            <activity
                android:name=".ui.PlayerActivity"
                android:exported="true"
                android:launchMode="singleTask">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.cast.tv.action.LOAD" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                </intent-filter>
    
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    
                    <data android:scheme="http" />
                    <data android:scheme="https" />
                    <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
                    <data android:mimeType="application/*" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
    
        </application>
```

ReceiverOptionProver class is the vanilla codelab's option provider.
What have I done wrong and how to fix this .. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Code is alright.My mistake was putting the APP_ID incorrectly.